# Not able to fill data into datatable using Datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I can't fill data into datatable. I can receive data in console.log(data). But how to fill that data into datatable. I am using dataTables.js and getting data from server side from ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'xxxxxx/xxxxxxx',
                method: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#datatable').dataTable({
                        data: data,
                        serverside:true,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'UserId' },
                            { 'data': 'UserDepartment' },
                            { 'data': 'UserCourse' },
                            { 'data': 'UserName' },
                            { 'data': 'UserBirthDate' },
                            { 'data': 'UserEmail' },
                            { 'data': 'UserContact' }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please explain in brief.. at least mention which technology you are using...

Comment: .net web service that return json data array.

Comment: ok so what is `$('#datatable').dataTable(` ??

Comment: this is my table in which i want to populate data. '#datatable is my table id.

Comment: how can we Feel data in database ?

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla not in database...feel data into jquery datatable.

Comment: is it MVC or Asp.net ?

Comment: my code is on asp.net

Comment: check this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5spCJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show data in `DataTable` and want get data from server side with web service then this would be proper way:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'xxxxxx/xxxxxxx',
    method: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#datatable').dataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
          { 'data': 'UserId' },
          { 'data': 'UserDepartment' },
          { 'data': 'UserCourse' },
          { 'data': 'UserName' },
          { 'data': 'UserBirthDate' },
          { 'data': 'UserEmail' },
          { 'data': 'UserContact' }
        ]
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Explanation : You are first getting data from web service then store data into javascript data object so you don't need *[Server-side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)*.
You just have to bind datatable by *[Javascript sourced data](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)*

If you want to use *[POST data](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html)* then you can do by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'xxxxxx/xxxxxxx',
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
              { 'data': 'UserId' },
              { 'data': 'UserDepartment' },
              { 'data': 'UserCourse' },
              { 'data': 'UserName' },
              { 'data': 'UserBirthDate' },
              { 'data': 'UserEmail' },
              { 'data': 'UserContact' }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: thanks...but i got following error...                                                  DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: you should check the data and also check the format in which webservice returning data i.e. json or text or ...

Comment: [{"UserId":2,"UserDepartment":"asp.net","UserCourse":"Chirag","UserName":"Employee","UserBirthDate":"4/1/1990 12:00:00 AM","UserEmail":"xxxxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com","UserContact":1234567},"}] i got above data into console.log(data)

Comment: there is extra comma in the end.. or your UserCintact data is wrong, it should be `"UserEmail":"xxxxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com","UserContact":"1234567"}]`

Comment: got same data u mention above..but error continue DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: which way you are using..? if you are calling data from datatables ajax then you should return json in this format : `{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    {
      "first_name": "Airi",
      "last_name": "Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "start_date": "28th Nov 08",
      "salary": "$162,700"
    }]
}`

Comment: i got data in json formate...but got error..datatables requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0

Comment: data = "[{"UserId":2,"UserDepartment":"asp.net","UserCourse":"Chirag","UserName":"Employee","UserBirthDate":"4/1/1990 12:00:00 AM","UserEmail":"xxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com","UserContact":123}]